# How to remove Share and CallDirectory Extensions and move all their functionalities to host app?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, callkit, share-extension

I have an iOS application that is composed of three separate projects. One is the main project(A.K.A container or host app) and the others are *Share Extension* and *CallDirectory Extension*.
I use Share Extension to enable my app to receive contact sharing, and I use CallDirectory Extension to block some phone numbers.

My requirement is to remove those two extension projects and end up with only one single project (host app project).
Is it possible to do so? And if yes how?

Comment: You need the extensions but they can all be in one project. It is probably easiest to just add the two additional targets to your main project and then copy the source files in

Comment: I need to know how to "add the two additional targets" in a Xamarin.iOS project.